# Django debug-toolbar. Can't see panel

Tags: django, django-debug-toolbar

This problem only debug-toolbar-1.0.1. 
If downgrade to django-debug-toolbar==0.9.4 - all works.
Django==1.5.5(I try Django 1.6, but problem the same).
I running server, and can't see panel(django-debug-toolbar).
In log:

```
[17/Jan/2014 03:05:16] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 10644
[17/Jan/2014 03:05:16] "GET /static/debug_toolbar/js/jquery.cookie.js HTTP/1.1" 304 3623
[17/Jan/2014 03:05:16] "GET /static/debug_toolbar/js/toolbar.js HTTP/1.1" 304 10216
[17/Jan/2014 03:05:16] "GET /static/debug_toolbar/css/toolbar.css HTTP/1.1" 304 22959
```

Anyone with a similar problem?
Sorry for my english.

Comment: Have you checked from your HTML source code if panel code is there and the panel would be just hidden?

Comment: I mean, django-debug-toolbar. And if i downgrade in my virtualenv version(from 1.0.1 => 0.9.4) - all work with the same code.

Answer (score 0):

There's a few changes between 0.9.4 and 1.0. The [changelist](http://django-debug-toolbar.readthedocs.org/en/1.0/changes.html#id1) recommends that you review the [installation](http://django-debug-toolbar.readthedocs.org/en/1.0/installation.html#quick-setup) and configuration docs and redo the setup in your projects.

I suggest retrying the setup as it suggests. If it still doesn't work, then update your question with your configuration, and somebody might be able to help.